# Restrict user to a directory vsftpd

Tags: permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I'm kind of new with Linux Ubuntu. I followed this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-on-ubuntu-12-04).

My user: `jer` is still able to see files by going back from his directory and open stuff and copy things. The thing that I found good is that he can't delete, edit or add rather than his own directory(which was before bugged but then I added `Owner:jer` from Winscp to that folder).

I want `jer` not able to view anything else than his folder! As `jer` could open other secret files and copy data.

Comment: Did you set the option `chroot_local_user=YES` in `/etc/vsftpd.conf` and _restarted_ the process afterwards?

Comment: Yes I did that, I set chroot_local_user=YES and then restarted the process but service vsftpd restart. Here is my config file: http://pastebin.com/S1tf1X6r

Comment: Strange. I just tried it with `vsftpd` version 3.0.2. Set `local_enable=YES; chroot_local_user=YES; allow_writable_chroot=YES`. I can log in with a local user account and the server jails me to my homedirectory, as it should.

Comment: I'm too in my home directory, but what the problem is, I can see other directories too. Which I don't want to happen.

Comment: You mean you can browse out of your home dir and view the content of `/home`?

Comment: That is exactly what I mean. I allotted my user to /home/jer. But what can jer do is go anywhere and see everything. He can't edit, download or upload anything but he can still see everything, open it and copy materials  from it. Which I don't want.

Comment: Is the user `jer` in `/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list`? Together with `chroot_local_user=YES` this becomes a list of users NOT to chroot.

Comment: Why is that I can't see see the file /etc/vsftpd.chroot.list? http://i.imgur.com/EPnDRNQ.png

Comment: Because you didn't create it. I thought you did, because in your config the option `chroot_list_file` was set. Which doesn't matter anyway if `chroot_list_enable=YES` is not set too. I'm really confused. I ran the *literally* same config you posted and my user is perfectly confined to his home directory. 
I still don't understand what is meant by "[...]which was before bugged but then I added Owner:jer from Winscp to that folder". Maybe you could expand your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I reinstalled vsftpd now and I made a vsftpd.chroot list file myself. http://i.imgur.com/3EPAr8D.png. But there is nothing in it even when I restarted the vsftpd.

Comment: There shouldn't be! You put usernames in the file that should NOT be chroot'ed. But that's not what you want. Perfectly fine to leave it empty.

Comment: "3) Make all necessary changes within the "files" subdirectory." When I did the process again, It was found that, when I upload things in the /home/test/file, the file wasn't being uploaded because of permission denied. Then I changed file folder's owner to test(username). This is what I meant with "bugged before" http://i.imgur.com/fwuJ5qs.png

Comment: There are weirdly two chroot_local_users=YES, which is should be uncommented?

Answer (score 3):

The manual:

https://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-ftp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04-vsftpd/

Setup FTP server on Ubuntu 14.04

Step 1 » Update repositories.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Step 2 » Install VsFTPD package using the below command.

```
$ sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```

Step 3 » After installation open /etc/vsftpd.conf file and make changes as follows.

»Uncomment the below lines (line no:29 and 33).

```
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
```

» Uncomment the below line (line no: 120 ) to prevent access to the other 
folders outside the Home directory.

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

and add the following line at the end.

```
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

» Add the following lines to enable passive mode.

```
pasv_enable=Yes
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=40100
```

Step 4 » Restart vsftpd service using the below command.

```
$ sudo service vsftpd restart
```

Step 5 » Now ftp server will listen on port 21. 
Create user with the below command.

Use /usr/sbin/nologin shell to prevent access to the bash shell for the ftp users .

```
$ sudo useradd -m john -s /usr/sbin/nologin
$ sudo passwd john
```

Step 6 » Allow login access for nologin shell . Open /etc/shells and add the following line at the end.

```
/usr/sbin/nologin
```